# How can I have one menu in all forms in VB.net Win Forms?

Tags: vb.net, winforms, inheritance

May I know if it is possible to have one header menu in all windows forms?
And if so, how can I make it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes its possible to have one header menu in all windows forms using MDI.

MDI is a popular interface because it allows you to have multiple documents (or forms) open in one application. Examples of MDI applications include Microsoft Word, Microsoft Excel, Microsoft PowerPoint®, and even the Visual Studio integrated development environment itself. Each application consists of one (or more) parent windows, each containing an MDI client area—the area where the child forms (or documents) will be displayed. Code you write displays as many instances of each of the child forms that you want displayed, and each child form can only be displayed within the confines of the parent window—this means you can't drag the child forms outside the MDI container.

For more details refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973874.aspx) blog. 
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Hi Arul Dinesh, it's customary in StackOverflow (and Superuser) answers to include a summary of the contents of a link or the highlights that specifically answer the question. The goal of SE sites is to become a resource of knowledge, of answers, for years to come. With a link-only answer, the op must dig through another resource to locate an answer he/she might not be sure about. Most importantly, if your link were to ever break, your answer is useless for anyone who visits this page in the future. Consider making an edit to your answer to add more details. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Two ways:

1. Add a User Control to your solution, place a Menu in the User Control and build the application. Then in the ToolBox you have the menu control that you can use on all forms.
2. Make a WinForm with a Menu then Inherit all your other forms from the base one.

Answer (score 0):

One solution for this is that you can create MDI application.